# How to import Sql Server 2008 database into sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

My problem is I am working on a project and its database is created in SQL Server 2008. But I has SQL SERVER 2012 installed in my PC. I cannot import this file into my sql server and also cannot connect this database file with visual studio 2013
Help me please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is creating a database backup in 2008, and restoring that into 2012. Should work without any issues, and the restore process will automatically upgrade the database to 2012.

Alternatively, it should also be possible to [detach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189625.aspx) the database from 2008, after which you can copy the files (Do not move them, but copy. That way if anything goes wrong, you have a fallback option). You should then be able to attach it in 2012, which again, will convert the database to 2012.

There's also an option of using the [copy database wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190775(v=sql.105).aspx) from inside SSMS, which also converts the database.

Please note that if you convert the database, from that moment onwards, all other developers will have to upgrade to 2012 as well.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. The only problem is i want to attach 2008 database file with my visual studio 2013. After the completion of the project i want to give them back the updated database but again in 2008 because they don't want to upgrade

Comment: @MuhammadNasirKhan - So it's a database file and not an actual SQL Server database? I'm not very familiar with the database files setup, but I would think that what you want simply is not possible. Once you convert a regular SQL database to a newer version, it then is not possible to "downgrade" it to the older version anymore.